# Error When Deleting records in DB using JSON API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem destroying or deleting a record in my rails app.

I'm having this error when deleting data and when I check the console log this error will occur:

```
error: ƒ ()
    responseText: "You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `find`. Please pass the id of the object by calling `.id`."
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
```

This is my Jquery when saving and deleting records:

```
$(".btn-pinner").on('click', function () {
    pinner = $(this)

    if (pinner.hasClass('checked')) {
        pinner.removeClass("checked")
        api_url = "/api/pin/destroy"
    } else {
        pinner.addClass("checked")
        api_url = "/api/pin"
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: api_url,
        data: {
            'content': pinner.data('content'),
            'article_id': pinner.data('article-id')
        },
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json)
        },
        error: function (json) {
            console.log(json)
        }
    })

});
// End pinner
```

In my Rails application, I have this `pin_controller.rb` to save and destroy data in jquery using ajax in `front/api/pin_controller.rb` folder:

```
class Front::Api::PinsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    def save_pin
      if params[:content].present?
        begin
          klass = Object.const_get(params[:content].camelize)
          source = klass.find(params[:article_id])
          source.pins.build(user_id: current_user.id)
          if source.save
            render json: true
          else
            render json: false
          end
        rescue => e
          render json: e.message
        end
      end
    end
  
    def destroy
      if params[:content].present?
        begin
          pin = Pin.where("user_id = ? and source_id = ? and source_type = ?", current_user.id, params[:article_id], params[:content].capitalize)
          if pin.present?
            pin.destroy(pin)
            render json: true
          end
        rescue => e
          render json: e.message
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my condition if pin is checked/not in views:

```
<% if pins.present? && pins.include?(source_id) %>
    <div class="btn-pinner checked" data-content="<%= source_type %>" data-article-id="<%= source_id %>"><span></span></div>
<% else %>
    <div class="btn-pinner" data-content="<%= source_type %>" data-article-id="<%= source_id %>"><span></span></div>
<% end %>
```

Why is it when calling the destroy method function:

```
def destroy
          if params[:content].present?
            begin
              pin = Pin.where("user_id = ? and source_id = ? and source_type = ?", current_user.id, params[:article_id], params[:content].capitalize)
              if pin.present?
                pin.destroy(pin)
                render json: true
              end
            rescue => e
              render json: e.message
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

And it will return an error:

```
"You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `find`. Please pass the id of the object by calling `.id`."
```

The save function is okay and can be saved into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These piece of code:

```rb
pin.destroy(pin)
```

is a source of your issue. 
according to [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-destroy) `destroy(*records)` accepts an array as argument.
So it wants to receive this:

```rb
pin.destroy(Pin.find(1), Pin.find(2))
```

and so on. But you are trying to pass `ActiveRecord Relation`.
My suggestion is to rewrite your piece of code to:

```
def destroy
  render(json: { message: 'Content is missing' }, status: :unprocessable_entity) and return unless params[:content].present?

  pin = ::Pin.find_by!(user_id: current_user.id, source_id: params[:article_id], source_type: params[:content].capitalize)
  if pin.destroy
    render json: { message: 'Successfully deleted' }, status: :ok
  else
    render json: { message: 'Can not destroy desired pin', error: pin.errors.messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render json: { message: 'Can not find desired pin' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver,  I was reading also the documentation of the  ActiveRecords.. this resolves the issue.